# When bi-weekly payments are made on a mortgage, is the bank required to zero out the interest?

Tags: mortgage, banking

Is a bank or loan company required to zero out the interest every 2 weeks when bi-weekly payments are made on a mortgage loan?

Comment: Note - a mortgage paid every two weeks is bi-weekly. 'Bi-monthly' means every two months. 'Semi-monthly' is twice per month. As you noted every 2 weeks in the question, I corrected the wording elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Money.SE. There is a high chance a similar Q&A already exists here, in which case this question would be closed as duplicate. Just a friendly note regarding that.

If you are talking about an actual bi-weekly mortgage, the accrued interest is paid and then principal is paid down, so yes, interest is 'zeroed' as you put it.

A bank that gives you a standard mortgage has no obligation to accept partial payments. You should ask your bank have they would handle it. They may simply return it as an invalid amount, or hold it until enough funds show up for the full payment.

If this is your desire, to pay a monthly mortgage bi-weekly, the right way to do it is simple.

- Set aside the half-payment every two weeks.
- Every first of the month make a regular payment if that's the amount set aside
- If the funds are 1-1/2 payments, send in the extra as a prepayment to principal. This will happen twice per year.

This method will make 13 payments per year in total $$, and will pay a 30 year mortgage off in less than 25 years.